# React Router Dom dos not renders child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is my code

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
//import Login from "./components/Login/Login";
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar/Sidebar.jsx";
import Topbar from "./components/topbar/Topbar.jsx";
import Home from "./Pages/home/Home";
import UserList from "./Pages/userList/UserList";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Topbar />
      <div className="container">
        <Sidebar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/user" element={<UserList />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the above code the `Topbar` and `Sidebar` components render but `Home` and `Userlist` components do not. What could be wrong?

Comment: I see no issue with the code you've provided. Are there any errors on the browser console? How are you running the app? What are the reproduction steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @motto That is for `react-router-dom@5`. It seems clear enough OP is using `react-router-dom@6` here. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#element

Comment: iam using react-router-dom@6. there is no console errors. i use npm start to run  the app it starts fine but the components inside routes and route do not renders

Comment: What is the current URL you are accessing and can you [edit] to include the `Home` and `UserList` component code as part of a complete [mcve]?

Comment: Code all seems to work as I'd expect. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-dos-not-renders-child-components-2zof5o) demo.

Comment: yes i can see its running fine in codesandbox. i just read minimal reproducible. i am going to create new project from scratch. thank you sir for your help..